# Proving that the intersection of two subgroups is a subgroup but the union of two subgroups is not a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whether $P\cap Q$ and $P\cup Q$ are subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253394/whether-p-cap-q-and-p-cup-q-are-subgroups)

How can we prove that the intersection of two subgroups is a subgroup. In more detail, if $G$ is a group and $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of $G$ then **$H_1 \cap H_2$** is a subgroup of $G$.

On the other hand, show by means of an example that $H_1 \cup H_2$ need not be a subgroup of $G$.