# A group with two non trivial subgroups is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> Let $G$ be a group. Suppose that $G$ has at most two nontrivial subgroups. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

---

Can anyone help me please to solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $G$ has no nontrivial subgroups, it is clearly cyclic. If $G$ has exactly one nontrivial subgroup $H$, consider the subgroup generated by a nonidentity element $g\in G\setminus H$.

Now suppose that $H$ and $K$ are the only nontrivial subgroups of $G$. Recall that a group is never the union of two proper subgroups. So pick some element $g\in G\setminus (H\cup K)$. What must $\langle g\rangle$ be?

Comment: If G has no nontrivial subgroups, it is clearly cyclic.But why?

Comment: @gumti If $G$ is trivial, you're done. Otherwise, pick a nonidentity element of $g$ of $G$. What must the subgroup $\langle g\rangle$ be? Remember, it cannot be nontrivial!

Comment: ["Recall that a group is never the union of two proper subgroups."](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334405)