# HK are subgroups of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm proving that if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ and $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I've tried pondering the fact that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ iff $HK = \langle H \cup K \rangle$ but I'm not sure how I'd use that.

I know that $H \cup K$ is a subgroup of $G$ because $H$ and $K$ are (EDIT: This is false)...Other than that, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Note that it is generally not the case that the union of two subgroups is itself a subgroup.

Comment: The only thing that you need to check is that $HK$ is closed under the group operation. How would you go about doing that?

Comment: The union of two subgroups $H$ and $K$ is a subgroup if and only if either $H\leq K$ or $K\leq H$. (For a reference, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334405/if-a-group-is-the-union-of-two-subgroups-is-one-subgroup-the-group-itself))

Comment: Hm, was it the intersection that was always a subgroup?

Comment: It is true that the intersection of two subgroups is always a subgroup (note that it might be trivial).

Comment: Yes, the intersection is always a subgroup. (The issue with unions is that they will not be closed under multiplication. For example, take two subgroups of the Klein 4-group each of which have order two, and are non-equal. They union to give you a set with three elements, which therefore cannot be a subgroup. The issue is that the two non-trivial elements of these two subgroups multiply to give you the fourth element of the Klein 4-group)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use normality to give you $kh=hk_1h^{-1}h$.

Comment: I understand you correctly?

$H$ is normal subgroup of $G$ so $H = aHa^{-1}$ which implies that $aha^{-1} \in H$ which further implies $khk^{-1} \in H$...So naturally $hkhk^{-1} \in H$...?

I'm not quite understanding the subscript on one of the $k$'s though

Comment: In your question it is the subgroup $K$ which is normal. So, as $K$ is normal we can conjugate $k$ by $h$ to get an element $k_1$ of $K$, $h^{-1}kh=k_1\in K$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean? Am I far off with my assumption of your answer? My foundation in this course is horrible, so try to go as easy as you can on the notation, please.

Comment: The first thing you have to realise is that in my answer (and your original post) it is the subgroup $K$ which is normal, *not* the subgroup $H$. The second thing (the main thing) is that because $K$ is normal we have that $h^{-1}kh\in K$ for our specific $K$, and all this means is that there exists some $k_1\in K$ such that $h^{-1}kh=k_1$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes this does make sense. I agree, there exists a $hkh^{-1} = k_1 \in K$. (Isn't it $hkh^{-1}$ and not $h^{-1}kh$? The definition reads: $aHa^{-1}$ in my textbook.)

Comment: Also, you are defining $kh$, but I would like to prove that $HK$ (i.e. $hk$) is a subgroup of $G$. Why is this?

Comment: The placing of the inverse doesn't matter, as $h=(h^{-1})^{-1}$. So you can just write $h^{-1}k(h^{-1})^{-1}=k_1\in K$ (and $h^{-1}\in G$). Anyway, the next thing you need to realise is that because of this you can write $k=h^{-1}k_1h$. This is the working which gives you my hint.

Comment: The purpose of my hint is to prove that $HK$ is closed under multiplication and inverses. This proves the result. I will leave it to you now to join up the dots - I need my bed!

Answer (score 1):

Use $hK=Kh$ to obtain $HK=KH$.

Comment: Wow...That's too easy. Why did I miss this method? Thank you.

Comment: @user3200098 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h,j \in H$.  Given $K$ is normal, $k\in K \implies xkx^{-1}\in K$ for all $x\in G\implies xK=Kx$.

1. Closure. $hK, jK\subseteq HK\implies hKjK = hjKK = hjK\subseteq HK$.
2. Identity. $e\in H$ and $e\in K\implies ee = e\in HK$.
3. Associativity. $HK\subseteq G$ and $G$ is associative.
4. Invertibility. $(hK)^{-1} = K^{-1}h^{-1}= Kh^{-1} = h^{-1}K \subseteq HK.$

Hence $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. $\Box$