# Union of finite subgroups not necessarily normal?

Tags: normal-subgroups

Suppose G is a group and n is a natural number. Show the union of subgroups
of G of order n is not necessarily a normal subgroup of G.

I'm guessing I use proof by contradiction, but I have no idea where to begin. Do I use the trivial subgroup?

Comment: In general, said union isn't even a subgroup

Comment: I am not even sure this union need be a subgroup.

Comment: Hint: The union of two subgroups $H_1,H_2 \subset G$ is a subgroup only if [one is contained in the other](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334405/if-a-group-is-the-union-of-two-subgroups-is-one-subgroup-the-group-itself).

Comment: Why on earth do you think a proof by contradiction is required? To show that some proposition $\phi$ is not necessarily true, what you do is produce a counter-example to $\phi$ (as those who have answered your question have done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may we be that union is not even a subgroup. For example, the union of all the subgroups of order two in $\;S_3\;$ :

$$\left\{\;(1),\,(12),\,(13),\,(23)\;\right\}\rlap{\;\,/}< S_3$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider $G=S_3$ and $n=2$. - Or even more trival: Consider any finite $G$ and $n$ not a divisor of $|G|$