# If a union of two subgroups of $G$ equals $G$, must one of the subgroups equal $G$?

Tags: group-theory

If the union of two subgroups of $G$ is the group $G$, does that mean one subgroup is $G$?

In a problem, it was proven to be true on this site. But take real numbers under addition as a group with Rational numbers as a subgroup and irrational numbers with ${0}$ as a subgroup. Then their union is a real number, but no subgroup is real numbers. So the statement is not true for all groups, right?

Comment: Irrational numbers under addition as a subgroup of $\Bbb R$? Are you sure of this?

Comment: under addition with 0 and negative irrational nubers.

Comment: Recall that the identity must be in the subgroup. What can you say to  $0$? Is it rational or irrational?

Comment: [The site's current main post for this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/334405/29335) (but I do not consider this a duplicate of it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result that one of the subgroups must be $G$ is correct.  What goes wrong with your example is that the irrational numbers together with $0$ are not a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.  For instance, $\pi$ and $1-\pi$ are both in this set, but their sum $\pi+(1-\pi)=1$ is not.

Comment: so any union of proper subgroups cannot be $G$?

Comment: That is correct (assuming you are taking a union of only two proper subgroups).

Comment: what if more than 2?

Comment: got it. klien 4 group

Answer (score 5):

The irrational numbers with $0$ do not form a subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$. $(\sqrt{2}+1)-\sqrt{2}=1$, so the irrationals with $0$ aren't closed under subtraction.

You're correct that at least one of them must be $G$. This follows from the more general fact that if the union of two groups is a group, then one of the groups must be (isomorphic to) a subgroup of the other.

Answer (score 2):

The decimal-part of an irrational number has a complement which together add to 1. Thus the integers are in any group of irrational numbers. SO your example doesn't work and you are false.

Comment: lol and +1 at "you are false"