# If $H_{3}$ is subgroup of $G$ that satisfies $H_3 \subseteq H_1 \cup H_2$ and $H_3 \not\subset H_2$, then $H_3 \subseteq H_1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(G,*)$ be group and $H_{1}, H_{2}$ subgroups of $G$. If $H_{3}$ is subgroup of $G$ that satisfies
>   $H_3 \subseteq H_1 \cup H_2$ and $H_3 \not\subset H_2$, then $H_3 \subseteq H_1$. Prove or give counterexample.

I really don't know how to solve this ,any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MoisheCohen That link of yours is not the same question.

Comment: Sorry, this is **not** an already asked question as Moishe marked it. I reopened it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's prove it by contradiction:

Assume $H_3\not\subseteq H_1$, so $H_3$ has two elements $h_1\in H_1\backslash H_2, h_2\in H_2\backslash H_1$. Then $h_1+h_2\in H_3\subseteq H_1\cup H_2\implies h_1+h_2\in H_1$ or $h_1+h_2\in H_2$.

If $h_1+h_2\in H_1$, then $h_2=(h_1+h_2)-h_1\in H_1$, contradiction. Similarly $h_1+h_2\in H_2$ leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Why $\;H_3\not\subset H_1\;$ implies the existence of those two elements $\;h_1,\,h_2\;$ *in* $\;H_3\;$ ?

Comment: It implies it has an element not in $H_1$, but since it's in $H_1\cup H_2$ it has to be in $h_2\in H_2$ Similar thing for $h_1$.

Comment: I agree with the first part: there exists $\;h_2\in H_3\setminus H_1\;$ , and since $\;h_2\in H_1\cup H_2\;$ , then in fact $\;h_2\in H_2\setminus H_1\;$ , but why the other one **too**? Why there is $\;h_1\in H_3\;$ s.t. $\;h_1\in H_1\setminus H_2\;$ ?

Comment: It's in the question: $H_3 \subseteq H_1 \cup H_2$ and $H_3 \not\subset H_2$

Comment: Sorry, then I meant otherwise in my past comment: it is clear there exists $\;h_2\in H_3\setminus H_1\subset H_1\cup H_2\;$ , so then $\;h_1\in H_2\setminus H_1\;$ , but why the other one too?

Comment: $H_3 \not\subset H_2\implies \exists h_1\in H_3\backslash H_2\subseteq (H_1\cup H_2)\backslash H_2=H_1\backslash H_2$

Answer (score 0):

It is well known and easy to prove that *[a group cannot be the union of two proper subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334405/if-a-group-is-the-union-of-two-subgroups-is-one-subgroup-the-group-itself)*. And $H_3 \subseteq H_1 \cup H_2 \iff H_3=(H_3 \cap H_1) \cup (H_3 \cap H_2)$. Hence $H_3=H_3 \cap H_1$ or $H_3=H_3 \cap H_2$, that is $H_3 \subseteq H_1$ or $H_3 \subseteq H_2$.