# If a composite element ab is in a set S, then is it true that a and b are in S?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If I have a set S under some operation, and the composite element (ab) is in S, then is it true that a,b must both be in S as well?

Could we have a situation where just a is in S but not b, or even neither being in S?

Thanks for any help. 
I need this question for group theory. I'm really trying to prove that if the union of two subgroups is a group then it must be true that one of them must be a subset of the other.

I was trying to prove it by contradiction, but I'm not sure if I can assume the statement above.

Comment: Say $H,K$ are two subgroups of a group $G$ such that their union $H\cup K$ is also a subgroup.  If neither is a subset of the other then choose $h,k$ such that  $h\in H,h\not \in K$, $k\in K, k\not \in H$.  $hk $ is in the union of course hence it is in either $H$ or $K$ (or both).  Can you finish from there?

Answer (score 4):

No: take the monoid $\mathbb{N}$ under multiplication. $-2$ and $-3$ are not in $\mathbb{N}$, but their product is.

For the second situation, take the same monoid under addition and pick two integers such that only one is negative but their sum is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the answer for your group theory class I can give an answer about groups

Generaly: Given any group $G$ and any proper subgroup $H$ you can take some $g\in G\backslash H$ and let $a=g,b=g^{-1}$ then neither $a,b\in G$ and $ab=1\in H$

For example: If you take $G = \mathbb{Z}$, $H=2\mathbb{Z}$ and $a=1,b=-1$ then $a,b\not\in H$ but $a+b=0\in H$.

Edit: @Daniel Schepler's comment is worth reading.

also you may want to look at this question [If a group is the union of two subgroups, is one subgroup the group itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334405/if-a-group-is-the-union-of-two-subgroups-is-one-subgroup-the-group-itself)

Comment: However, if $H$ is a subgroup with $ab \in H$, then $a \in H \implies b \in H$ and vice versa.  So in this case, you can't have "just $a$ is in $H$ but not $b$".