# Group which can be written as a union of proper normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $\{N_j\}_{j \in J} $ be a family of proper normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G=\cup_{j \in J} N_j$ and $N_i \cap N_j =\{e\}$ for every $i\ne j \in J$ .

Then how to prove that $G$ is abelian ?

I can show that $ab=ba$ whenever $a\in N_i, b \in N_j$ for some $i\ne j$ . So if I can only show each $N_i$ is abelian, we're done. Unfortunately I'm unable to show that.

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $N$ be one of the normal subgroups and let $C$ be its centraliser in $G$. This is a subgroup of $G$ and you have shown that $C\cup N=G$, but a group cannot be the union of two proper subgroups, so $C=G$ and $N$ is central.

Comment: (I think it's worth noting $C\cup N=G$ because $C$ contains all the other $N$s.)

Comment: "a group cannot be the union of two proper subgroups" - very simple proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/334411/169852)